# Touch Began method issue?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have created an app in which I want to use the touchbegan method. For this I have used the following code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //Get all the touches.
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];

    //Number of touches on the screen
    if([allTouches count] > 0 && self.view!=comparedView.view) 
    {
        //Navigate to next screen here likewise you generally do

        ActionViewController *actController = [[ActionViewController alloc] init];
        UINavigationController *nvController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                initWithRootViewController:actController];
        nvController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
        CGRect frame = [[nvController navigationBar] frame];
         frame = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0, 320.0, 460.0);
        [[nvController navigationBar] setFrame:frame];
        [self setView:[nvController view]];
        [actController release];

    }

}
```

On touch on anywhere on screen for my 1st view the following code will be executed and it will go to the next view. But problem is that when i go to the last view and touch on the imageview in that view the above method is called.

I am not getting how it is taking place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`  will be called every time till the view controller get released or touch events are disabled.

the view are being created and added to the same view conroller every time so the touch beganis called for all the views

Comment: no but it is not getting called in the 2nd view it is getting called in the third view only in perticular area not the whole screen.

Comment: self.view!=comparedView.view print NSLog for the same and you will find the reason